# When running clang++ in Arch it immediately segfaults

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I get the following output if I simply run `clang++` without arguments in my terminal (Konsole). I installed Clang from the `extra/clang` version 7.0.1-1 package with kernel `4.19.8-arch1-1-ARCH`. Other packages like gcc work fine and rebooting did not make a difference.

```
[overv@arch ~]$ clang++
Stack dump:
0.      Program arguments: clang++ 
1.      Compilation construction
/usr/bin/../lib/libLLVM-7.so(_ZN4llvm3sys15PrintStackTraceERNS_11raw_ostreamE+0x2b)[0x7f41d2c5db1b]
/usr/bin/../lib/libLLVM-7.so(_ZN4llvm3sys17RunSignalHandlersEv+0x34)[0x7f41d2c5bf74]
/usr/bin/../lib/libLLVM-7.so(+0x8fd0fe)[0x7f41d2c5c0fe]
/usr/bin/../lib/libc.so.6(+0x37e00)[0x7f41d1562e00]
/usr/bin/../lib/libLLVM-7.so(_ZNSt23_Sp_counted_ptr_inplaceIN4llvm3sys2fs6detail12DirIterStateESaIS4_ELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE14_M_get_deleterERKSt9type_info+0x1b)[0x7f41d2bb4ecb]
/usr/bin/../lib/libclangBasic.so.7(+0x1ddd04)[0x7f41d2207d04]
/usr/bin/../lib/libclangDriver.so.7(+0x114e69)[0x7f41d1b06e69]
/usr/bin/../lib/libclangDriver.so.7(+0x115de0)[0x7f41d1b07de0]
/usr/bin/../lib/libclangDriver.so.7(+0x12a895)[0x7f41d1b1c895]
/usr/bin/../lib/libclangDriver.so.7(_ZNK5clang6driver6Driver12getToolChainERKN4llvm3opt7ArgListERKNS2_6TripleE+0x34b)[0x7f41d1a5aacb]
/usr/bin/../lib/libclangDriver.so.7(_ZN5clang6driver6Driver16BuildCompilationEN4llvm8ArrayRefIPKcEE+0x7f3)[0x7f41d1a65e93]
clang++(main+0x10bc)[0x55d8d255b0ec]
/usr/bin/../lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x7f41d154f223]
clang++(_start+0x2e)[0x55d8d255d5fe]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Is that version currently unstable to the point of being broken or did I do something wrong? How would I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by installing system updates including the `llvm-libs` package.